# php mailer выдает ошибку/

Tags: php, hosting, phpmailer

```
<?php 

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

$text = $_POST['text'];

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'mail@mail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = 'pass)'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('mail@mail.ru'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('you@mail.ru');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с tesla&mc';
$mail->Body    = '' .$text . 'токен';
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: thankyou.html');
}
?>
```

после заполнения и отправки перекидывает на eror и не знаю что делать.
выдает такю ошибку

> 2022-02-05 20:56:25 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.mail.ru:465, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2022-02-05 20:56:25 Connection: opened 2022-02-05 20:56:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtpng1.m.smailru.net ESMTP ready (Looking for Mail for your domain? Visit https://biz.mail.ru) 2022-02-05 20:56:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO grimacecoin.space 2022-02-05 20:56:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtpng1.m.smailru.net 250-SIZE 73400320 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 2022-02-05 20:56:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2022-02-05 20:56:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2022-02-05 20:56:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: b3RwcmF2a2EuZ3JpbUBtYWlsLnJ1 2022-02-05 20:56:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2022-02-05 20:56:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: Uk5WUDF1ZXBhM3kp 2022-02-05 20:56:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Authentication failed. Please verify your account by going to https://e.mail.ru/login?email=otpravka.grim@mail.ru 2022-02-05 20:56:25 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Authentication failed. Please verify your account by going to https://e.mail.ru/login?email=otpravka.grim@mail.ru 2022-02-05 20:56:25 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2022-02-05 20:56:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2022-02-05 20:56:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 smtpng1.m.smailru.net closing connection 2022-02-05 20:56:25 Connection: closed 2022-02-05 20:56:25 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Error

Comment: `Authentication failed. Please verify your account`. Скорее всего либо пароль неверный, либо нужно включить отправку писем по smtp в настройках ящика через веб-интерфейс. Многие почтовики это выключают по-дефолту.

Comment: А где эта настройка на почту mail.ru не подскажете?

Comment: Войти в почту, затем Пароль и безопасность > Пароли для внешних приложений > Создать. Похоже, что это их новая настройка. После создания появится окно с паролем и надпись "Введите его вместо основного пароля, когда будете входить в аккаунт в почтовом приложении. Рекомендуем создавать для каждого приложения отдельный пароль."